# Get the whole table with column has more than 255 characters from access database using R

Tags: sql, r, ms-access, rodbc

I use RODBC library to get table from an access database in R.

```
Path = "C:\\test.accdb"
conn = paste("DSN=MS Access Database;DBQ=",Path,sep="")
connect = odbcDriverConnect(connection = conn)
```

then I want to load the data in table A:

```
SQL="SELECT * FROM A"
tableA=sqlQuery(connect,SQL)
```

A column in table A has more than 255 characters in it. The result in *tableA* only has the first 255 characters of that column. How can I get the whole complete table using R from this database?

Comment: I wonder if the same driver is used to read access and excel files... https://support2.microsoft.com/kb/189897